# MVC5 return status 500 custom page, tried normal solutions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-codes, internal-server-error, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I want to be able to control a redirect to a different page or return a different view on certain handled errors.  I can create custom pages with status 404, 403, 418, and it displays the page fine, but when I try to return 500 it overrides it with a default page.  I've tried the normal solutions.  Using TrySkipIisCustomErrors to get by IIS intercepting the 500 error.  I have no filter.cs and register no filters in application_Start().  I've tried adding and removing [HandleError] from the method and that doesn't make a difference.

```
[NonAction]
    [HandleError]
    private ActionResult error(Exception e)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Response.StatusDescription = "Internal server error: " + e.Message;
        Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        ErrorModel errorModel = new ErrorModel();
        errorModel.error = e.Message;
        return View(viewName: "error", model: errorModel);
    }
```

That's the method that the error is redirected to and returns the view to be displayed.  I can change the first line to other StatusCodes and it works fine, but 500 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a weird fluke with Razor.  The RenderBody() adds `<body>` tags if none are in the document, apparently unless you return 500 in your status header.  Then it doesn't add the `<body>` tags, and the HTML returns malformed which was causing my problem.